# I am having a typical error in doing this unallocated pointer dereferencing

Tags: c

Behold the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void function ();
int main()
{
   int * a;
   *a=9;//this is supposed to give error as I am trying to 
            // dereference an unallocated pointer
           // but it does not
   printf("%d",*a);
   function();
  }
  void function()
  {
        int * a;
         *a=9;//this gives an error as I am trying to 
            // dereference an unallocated pointer
           printf("%d",*a);
           return;
     }
```

Output is 9 and then the program crashes...
Why?
The difference for main() and function()
For main() we declare a pointer type then without the use of calloc or malloc is it by default allocated memory?

Comment: ***Output is 9 and then the program crashes... Why?*** You have UB since you did not allocate space for your integer.

Comment: Undefined behavior can do anything, including "work".

Comment: ***//this is supposed to give error*** No it is not. Decades ago `c` has chose to not do so for performance reasons.

Comment: You might want to try printing out the value of the pointer in each case just to see where your uninitialized pointer is pointing. `printf("%p\n", a)` should do it. Best of luck.

Comment: Also take a look at the include library, it is spelled `stdio.h` not `studio.h`. You might get problems in C99.

Comment: Yup the autocorrect did it as I was typing on my phone while working on PC.. Due to thunderstorm I don't have internet on PC today

Comment: Undefined behavior isn't "suppose to" do anything but make your life hard.

Answer (score 4):

You either got lucky with the uninitialized data, or your compiler is optimizing the pointer away.

When you do a thing like that with

```
int *a;
*a = 9;
printf("%d\n", *a);
```

The compiler can just turn that into

```
puts("9");
```

Because it can know and see all of the values.

That's probably why your function call version crashes. Because the compiler has to generate a function that can be called by other code modules.

This sort of thing will vary a lot based on compiler, compiler version, and of course the flags given to the compiler.